# Почему появились пустые места вместо табов в PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Сами пропали табы в PhpStorm. Отступает корректно, но остаются пустые места вместо символа стрелки. Кто знает, как их включить обратно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

В скриншоте настроек стрелки есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance, Show whitespaces`. Если не поможет, попробуйте изменить цвет Whitespaces (`Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General, Text/Whitespaces`) - может, их просто не видно?

Comment: Елена, первый ваш совет помог) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> (Нужный вам язык) -> Галочка Use Tab character

Comment: Это у меня везде проставлено http://joxi.ru/E2pe0VyU103yAY

Comment: Какое расширение у файла с которым вы работаете сейчас?

Comment: Не важно, не работает как и в .scss, так и в .tpl

Comment: И в .html, .css и так далее

Comment: Странно. У меня данный метод сработал. У вас какая версия программы? Не обновлялись недавно?

Comment: Предпоследняя вроде как. Но ведь раньше работало, черт побери. Ладно, может еще кто то подскажет что то. Спасибо за ответ!